# Execute SQL statements automatically after Postgresql service starts

Tags: postgresql

Would like to setup Postgresql 8.3 and above on Windows to automatically execute a series of SQL statements after the server has started.

Can't seem to find any information. Any ideas ?

Comment: It might not be possible. (Which role would it use to run the statements?) What do you want to run on the startup?

Comment: I would like to execute a few queries to pull some of the table data into the cache to improve the first use performance of our application.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by creating another service that depends on Postgres & launches something that runs these queries, but in reality there's no point: Postgres will pull data into its cache (and the OS disk cache) on the first query it runs.
The Postgres cache will be voided any time Postgres needs that memory for something else (a big join).  The OS disk cache will be voided any time the system needs that memory (big application, someone else pulling data off disk, etc.)

Bottom line: You might improve first-use performance if someone hits your application *right after startup*, otherwise these caches will start naturally emptying out and your optimization will drain away with them.